# Monitor loses input signal periodically?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, computer-building

I recently installed a new video card and PSU on my machine and since then, the input signal to the monitor gets lost periodically.

The LED light on the monitor doesn't turn off or change colors.

What would be the best way to diagnose this issue?

550W PSU newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817341022

9800 GTX+ newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130339

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, the DVI cable I'm using is new. I bought it with the video card.

I have a VGA->DVI adapter so I will test the monitor with the VGA cable.

Answer (score 0):

Just some quick suggestions:

- Have you any means of testing whether the monitor cable is maybe damaged ?
- Can you try connecting some other monitor to your computer, as to exclude the graphics card from the list of suspects ?